# How can we integrate our windows Phone 7 apps for posting data on Google Plus Wall?

Tags: c#

How can we integrate our windows Phone 7 apps for posting data on Google Plus Walls. If any one know how to do this please provide me API and sample code for posting data on google plus wall using WP7 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't as noted **[here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)**

```
Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.
All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.
```